# HTML file "missing" from GH pages actually just lacks an extension

Tags: github-pages

30 minutes ago I pushed [an HTML file (of Unicode categories)](https://github.com/qwertie/home/blob/master/misc/CharCategoriesTable.html). Half an hour later the [corresponding address on the site](http://david.loyc.net/misc/CharCategoriesTable.html) still gives a 404. (A [green checkmark here](https://github.com/qwertie/home/commits/master) indicates that 25 minutes ago "GitHub Pages successfully built your site." The [deployment activity log](https://github.com/qwertie/home/deployments/activity_log?environment=github-pages) agrees it was deployed.)

It turns out that the HTML file was deployed without the .html extension. Which is *very* strange, because markdown files on the same site ([example](http://david.loyc.net/misc/Atlas-Shrugged-book-review.html)) **are** deployed with an .html extension.

Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my [_config.yml](https://github.com/qwertie/home/blob/master/_config.yml)?

Edit: OMFG, I uploaded a [modified Unicode character table](http://david.loyc.net/misc/CharCategories.html) and this one requires the html extension - without .html it's 404! So now, the original file works with or without .html, but the new file requires .html. I guess GH pages is just... glitchy.